# Enviar múltiples modelos en solicitud desde el servicio angular al método c#

Tags: c#, angular

Soy nuevo en Angular y actualmente estoy en un gran proyecto en el que trabaja mucha gente, por lo que el proyecto se basa en Angular para el front-end y C# para el back-end.

Entonces, el proyecto tiene algunos servicios que llaman al servicio backend como:

**front**:

```
   public editProfileClient(profileClient) {
        return this.http
          .post(this.url + '/editProfileClient', profileClient)
          .pipe(map((result: ProfileClientModel) => result));
      }
```

**back**:

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> EditProfileClient(ProfileClient profileClient)
        {
          //irrelevant code here
          return Ok(model);
        }
```

Esto está funcionando bien, pero ahora quiero enviar un nuevo modelo llamado `Salary` a esa solicitud, así que cambié el controlador como:

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> EditProfileClient(ProfileClient profileClient, Salary salary)
```

pero no tengo idea de cómo puedo enviarlo en el front, así que lo recibo, pero no puedo llamarlo:

```
  public editProfileClient(profileClient, salary) {
    return this.http
      .post(this.url + '/editProfileClient', profileClient, salary)
      .pipe(map((result: ProfileClientModel) => result));
  }
```

Si trato de hacer eso, el método devuelve un error:

> Argument of type 'OperatorFunction<ProfileClientModel,
> ProfileClientModel>' is not assignable to parameter of type
> 'OperatorFunction<ArrayBuffer, ProfileClientModel>'.

Como puedo lograr esto?

Answer (score 0):

1.- Creas una clase que contenga las otras clases

```
public class ProfileClientRequest{
  public ProfileClient profileClient {get;set;}
  public Salary salary{get;set;}
}
```

2.- En el action del controller

```
public async Task<ActionResult> EditProfileClient(ProfileClientRequest pcq)
```

3.- En angular

```
public editProfileClient(profileClient, salary) {
    return this.http
      .post(this.url + '/editProfileClient', { profileClient: profileClient, salary: salary})
      .pipe(map((result: ProfileClientModel) => result));
  }
```